# Croogo: Themed views for plugin

Tags: cakephp, view, croogo

I'm using Croogo for the first time And I have a problem: I want to theme some views (ctp) from Plugins.

- to theme elements from **app\Plugin\Nodes\View\Nodes\** I had to put files in **app\View\Themed\MyTheme\Nodes\** (and that's OK!)
- to change **app\Plugin\Comments\View\Elements\** I had to put files in **app\View\Plugin\Comments\Elements\** (didn't found place in MyTheme directory, where it work)

but when I want to theme admin (admin.cpt, admin_full.cpt) views, I completely don't know how to do that:

- **\app\Plugin\Croogo\View\Layouts\** => **app\View\Plugin\Croogo\Layouts\** : NOPE
- **\app\Plugin\Croogo\View\Layouts\** => **app\View\Layouts\Croogo\** : NOPE
- **\app\Plugin\Croogo\View\Layouts\** => **app\View\Themed\Plugin\Croogo\Layouts\** : NOPE
- **\app\Plugin\Croogo\View\Layouts\** => **app\View\Themed\MyTheme\Croogo\Layouts\** : NOPE
- **\app\Plugin\Croogo\View\Layouts\** => **app\View\Themed\MyTheme\Layouts\** : NOPE
- **\app\Plugin\Croogo\View\Layouts\** => **app\View\Themed\MyTheme\Layouts\Croogo\** : NOPE

Do anybody know how to solve that without editing views in Croogo Plugin ?

*Croogo version: 1.5.4*

Best Regards, Cezary Daniel Nowak

Comment: I found a solution.

In **app/Config/bootstrap.php** there should be line pointing at specific Theme:

`Configure::write('Site.admin_theme', 'MyTheme');`

Now admin theme Layout files can be placed in the **app\View\Themed\MyTheme\Layouts\\**